# Angular 2 Fusion Chart integration

Tags: javascript, angular, import, fusioncharts

I am just starting with Angular2.I am trying to integrate [Fusion charts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/) with Angular2. I have installed all the necessary modules ([@types/fusioncharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/fusioncharts) and [fusioncharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fusioncharts)). Below is fusionchart component code.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import * as FusionCharts from "FusionCharts";
import '../../node_modules/fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts.js';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id.toString(),
    templateUrl: 'fusioncharts2.component.html'
})

export class FusionChartsComponent2 {
    revenueChart: any;

    constructor() {

    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.chartConfig()
    }

    public chartConfig() {
        this.revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
            type: 'column3d',
            renderAt: 'chart-container',
            width: '500',
            height: '300',
            dataFormat: 'json',
            dataSource: {
                "chart": {
                    "caption": "Monthly revenue for last year",
                    "subCaption": "Harry's SuperMart",
                    "xAxisName": "Month",
                    "yAxisName": "Revenues (In USD)",
                    "paletteColors": "#0075c2",
                    "valueFontColor": "#ffffff",
                    "baseFont": "Helvetica Neue,Arial",
                    "captionFontSize": "14",
                    "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
                    "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
                    "placeValuesInside": "1",
                    "rotateValues": "1",
                    "showShadow": "0",
                    "divlineColor": "#999999",
                    "divLineIsDashed": "1",
                    "divlineThickness": "1",
                    "divLineDashLen": "1",
                    "divLineGapLen": "1",
                    "canvasBgColor": "#ffffff"
                },

                "data": [
                    {
                        "label": "Jan",
                        "value": "420000"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Feb",
                        "value": "810000"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Mar",
                        "value": "720000"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Apr",
                        "value": "550000"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "May",
                        "value": "910000"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Jun",
                        "value": "510000"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Jul",
                        "value": "680000"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Aug",
                        "value": "620000"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Sep",
                        "value": "610000"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Oct",
                        "value": "490000"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Nov",
                        "value": "900000"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Dec",
                        "value": "730000"
                    }
                ]
            }
        });
        this.revenueChart.render();
    }

}
```

app.module.ts

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
    import { InputTextModule, DataTableModule, ButtonModule, DialogModule } from 'primeng/primeng';

    // Import angular2-fusioncharts
    import { FusionChartsModule } from 'angular2-fusioncharts';

    // Import FusionCharts library
    import * as FusionCharts from 'fusioncharts';
    // Import FusionCharts Charts module
    import Charts = require('fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts');


    // used to create fake backend
    import { fakeBackendProvider } from './_helpers/index';
    import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';
    import { BaseRequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

    // Imports for loading & configuring the in-memory web api
    import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { routing } from './app.routing';

    import { AlertComponent } from './_directives/index';
    import { AuthGuard } from './_guards/index';
    import { AlertService, AuthenticationService, UserService, 
HeroSearchService, HeroService, InMemoryDataService } from 
'./_services/index';
    import { CarService } from './cars/carservice';
    import { HomeComponent } from './home/index';
    import { DashboardComponent, HeroDetailComponent, HeroSearchComponent, 
    HeroesComponent } from './dashboard/index';
    import { AppChildComponent, ParentComponent } from 
    './parentchild/index';
    import { ContentComponent } from './content/index';
    import { DataTableComponent } from './datatable/index';
    import { FusionChartsComponent } from './fusioncharts/index';
    import { FusionChartsComponent2 } from './fusioncharts2/index';
    import { JqDataTableComponent } from './jqdatatable/index';
    import { JsTreeComponent } from './jstree/index';
    import { LoginComponent } from './login/index';
    import { RegisterComponent } from './register/index';

    import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from 
    '@angular/common';

    @NgModule({
        imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            BrowserAnimationsModule,
            FormsModule,
            HttpModule,
            InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService, { 
passThruUnknownUrl: true }),
            routing,
            InputTextModule,
            DataTableModule,
            ButtonModule,
            DialogModule,
            FusionChartsModule.forRoot(FusionCharts, Charts)
        ],
        declarations: [
            AppComponent,
            AlertComponent,
            HomeComponent,
            DashboardComponent,
            FusionChartsComponent,
            FusionChartsComponent2,
            HeroDetailComponent, HeroSearchComponent, HeroesComponent,
            AppChildComponent, ParentComponent,
            ContentComponent,
            DataTableComponent,
            JqDataTableComponent,
            JsTreeComponent,
            LoginComponent,
            RegisterComponent
        ],
        providers: [
            AuthGuard,
            AlertService,
            AuthenticationService,
            UserService,
            HeroSearchService,
            HeroService,
            CarService,
            // providers used to create fake backend
            fakeBackendProvider,
            MockBackend,
            BaseRequestOptions,
            { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
        ],
        bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })

    export class AppModule { }
```

I am getting below error when execute my code.

```
    vendor.js:28488 [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
    vendor.js:4073 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
    app.js:27495 GET http://localhost:9966/fusioncharts.charts.js (404)
    vendor.js:28300 [WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.
```

If I include fusionchart cdn in index.html via script or if fusionchart.js present in app folder, that error is fixed. Though fusionchart.js code is in app bundle, it always look for fusionchart.js in the root app folder. Even I tried importing by pointing to node_modules some thing like this "***import '../../node_modules/fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts.js';***" still no effect. Is it proper way to include js via script tag in html? Any other way to fix this error?

Comment: can you just update the app.module.ts file too

Comment: I have used highcharts for integration and there you need to import in app.module.ts . link to the app module i used , its must the same forfusion chart https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/AngularConcepts/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: @RahulSingh I have added app.module.ts

Comment: you need to post this line in your index file <script src="https://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script> and i guess this is what you have mentioned in the question it mandatory to inculde i guess. please check this  link https://www.sitepoint.com/chart-component-angular2-fusioncharts/

Comment: Refer the link https://github.com/fusioncharts/angular2-fusioncharts

Comment: @Vignesh Already tried. If I try to implement other examples than the given in the link, I am facing the same error

Comment: Can you post webpack.common.ts file

Comment: Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode. So enableProdMode() in main.ts file

Comment: @Vignesh Tried. No effect. How you relate prod mode with this error??

Comment: The error 4073 relates to that

Comment: Have you fixed the issue

Comment: @Vignesh Error 4073 doesn't matter. That fusionchart.js 404 error is still there. Hope you understand my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143690/discussion-between-vignesh-and-shamoh).

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same issue. You can fix this by updating app.module.ts

update this part from

```
// Import FusionCharts Charts module
import Charts = require('fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts');
```

TO

```
// Import FusionCharts Charts module
import * as Charts from 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts';
FusionChartsModule.fcRoot(FusionCharts, Charts);
```

And yes, this won't work "import '../../node_modules/fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts.js';" since this isn't the correct way of importing FusionCharts

You can also refer to the updated documentation on the correct usage
https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/angular/angular/configure-your-chart-using-angular

Answer (score 0):

You can try by implementing the below code -

// Setup needed in app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, enableProdMode } from '@angular/core'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FusionChartsModule } from 'angular-fusioncharts';

// Load FusionCharts
import * as FusionCharts from 'fusioncharts';
// Load Charts module
import * as Charts from 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts';
// Load fusion theme
import * as FusionTheme from 'fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion';

// Add dependencies to FusionChartsModule
FusionChartsModule.fcRoot(FusionCharts, Charts, FusionTheme)

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FusionChartsModule
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

// In app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent { 
    dataSource: Object;
    chartConfig: Object;

    constructor() {
         this.chartConfig = {
            width: '700',
            height: '400',
            type: 'column2d',
            dataFormat: 'json',
        };

        this.dataSource = {
            "chart": {
              "caption": "Countries With Most Oil Reserves [2017-18]",
              "subCaption": "In MMbbl = One Million barrels",
              "xAxisName": "Country",
              "yAxisName": "Reserves (MMbbl)",
              "numberSuffix": "K",
              "theme": "candy",
            },
            "data": [{
              "label": "Venezuela",
              "value": "290"
            }, {
              "label": "Saudi",
              "value": "260"
            }, {
              "label": "Canada",
              "value": "180"
            }, {
              "label": "Iran",
              "value": "140"
            }, {
              "label": "Russia",
              "value": "115"
            }, {
              "label": "UAE",
              "value": "100"
            }, {
              "label": "US",
              "value": "30"
            }, {
              "label": "China",
              "value": "30"
            }]
          };

    }
}
```

//in app.component.html

```
<fusioncharts
    [chartConfig]=chartConfig
    [dataSource]=dataSource >
</fusioncharts>
```

Document reference - https://www.fusioncharts.com/angular2-js-charts?framework=angular2